# What is the equivalent of SQL Server 2005 IMAGE Datatype in C#

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, c#-4.0, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure that I am calling in C# in data layer. So it has many parameters and one of which is bytes array

```
byte[] value
```

However, the column in the stored procedure and hence the table is `Image`.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

For expert folks, I understand it won't be supported in future, but currently our business have only this, so what is the `DBType` value I should put in C#?

Binary? Byte? sByte?

```
byte[] imagePDFByte = value;

 db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@content", *DbType.Binary*, imagePDFByte);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+datatype+mapping+image+sql+server

Comment: Ever since 2005 was launched, **over a decade ago**, there's been [this note in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): "ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them.". So I'd say the first thing, even if you are going to continue to use an unsupported version of SQL Server, is at least the heed the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it won't be supported in future

No, not in future. It is not supported **now**. Extended support for SQL Server 2005 ended 3 years ago!

You can see SQL Server data type mappings in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). For `image` you should use `DbType.Binary`.